# I want to make a program that can download files automatically from website

Tags: download, click

There are buttons to click for downloading files in some websites.
So I need to make a program that can automatically download.
or automatically click those buttons.

I need your help. Thank you

-

-

I want to know ways to solve that problem or I want to get related url

Comment: Hi and welcome! Stack Overflow does not provide tutorials. Can you share your research? Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)